# Jquery off() and on() when adding options to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, select

I have a problem when i add options dinamically to select elements.
I only register the onChange event after add the options, but the event is fired anyway.
I can i prevent this behaviour?

```
$.each(this.formDependentGroupData, function (index, data) {
            el = $("*[dependent-group='" + data.dependentGroup + "']");


            el.off('change',function (e) { //** this one

                alert('ofchange');
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    obj.resetLists($('#' + obj.tableId + "_editorForm"), $(this));
                    obj.dependentLists($(this), $(this).val());
                } else {
                    obj.resetLists($('#' + obj.tableId + "_editorForm"), $(this));
                }
            });
            el.append(data.options);

            if (data.val){
                el.val(data.val);


                  el.on('change',function (e) { //** this one

                    alert('change');
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    if ($(this).val()) {
                        obj.resetLists($('#' + obj.tableId + "_editorForm"), $(this));
                        obj.dependentLists($(this), $(this).val());
                    } else {
                        obj.resetLists($('#' + obj.tableId + "_editorForm"), $(this));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

this add the options `el.append(data.options);` and the event is registered later, but it is fired.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault();` instead of `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Comment: I need the event but only after the options are filled

Comment: Is `$("#" + obj.tableId + "_editorForm")` a select element?

Comment: it is a form..."*[dependent-group]" are select elements

Comment: Adding options to a select or changing it's value programmatically doesn't trigger a change event. something else is triggering it, somewhere other than within this code.